# horizontal line for local TOC in chapters

Tags: table-of-contents

I setup local table of contents for each chapter in a document using the following code:

```
 \newcommand{\chaptertoc}[1][Contents]{%  
   \etocsettocstyle{\addsec*{#1}}{}%   
   \localtableofcontents%
 \noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}} 
 }
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Instead, I would like to have a line separation between the text `Contents` and the localtoc. It should look something similar to this:

[image]

I tried adding the line  `\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}` before `\etocsettocstyle{\addsec*{#1}}{}%`  but it is not working as desired.

Could someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the minitoc package:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{minitoc}
  
\begin{document}
\dominitoc
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter title}
\minitoc

\section{Test 1}
hello
\section{Test 2}
hello
\section{Test 3}
hello

\end{document}
```

[image]